# Axios: Send null value as param in request

Tags: axios, http-request-parameters

Is there a possibility to pass a parameter with the value of null to axios? It seems that [null values are just ignored](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/lib/helpers/buildURL.js)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An empty string should do the trick.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('location_id', '');
axios.post('/location/update', data)
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```